# fade out and fade in card element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade out and fade in a card element. My **html** looks like this:

```
<form class=" mt-4 mw-800 center-block animated fadeInUp">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 content">
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">{{ $random_idea->title }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ $random_idea->description }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button id="idea" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block">
        Geef mij een ander idee</button>
</form>
```

My **jQuery** code looks like this:

```
$( "#idea" ).click(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/idea",
        success: function(response) {
            $(".card").fadeOut();

            $('<div class="card card-primary">' +
                '<div class="card-header">' +
                  '<h3 class="card-title">' + response.title + '</h3>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="card-body">' + response.description +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>').appendTo('.content').fadeIn();

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

The card div is fading out and fading in. But there is a delay, it's not shown good.

My lay-out looks like this:

[image]

When you click on the button the card fades out and another card fades in. But it's not smooth. Do you have any ideas to help me?

Comment: You need to position one absolutely so that they occupy the same space when the fading happens - try adding a class of absolute (where you position that absolutely) before the fadeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are asynchronous. So, the new and old elements are fading in/out together. But, those methods gets a callback will call after the animation. So, you can rewrite your `success` function as follows:

```
$(".card").fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).remove();

  $('<div class="card card-primary">' +
    '<div class="card-header">' +
      '<h3 class="card-title">' + response.title + '</h3>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="card-body">' + response.description + '</div>' +
  '</div>').appendTo('.content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
var html = '<div class="card card-primary">' +
                '<div class="card-header">' +
                  '<h3 class="card-title">' + response.title + '</h3>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="card-body">' + response.description +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>';

$(html).hide().appendTo(".content").fadeIn(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not going smooth is because you didnt give a speed within your fadeout/fadein function.

If you read the docs on https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp you notice the syntax accepts a speed `$(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)`

Wenn you fill in the speed of your `fadein()` and your `fadeout()` it should go smooth.